# I want to enable call forwarding option enable in blackberry through program is is it possible?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I want to enable call forwarding option enable in blackberry through program  (the forwarding number is set previously just i want to enable the option) is is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but call forwarding programmatically is not supported.